# Invoice using Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, oop

I designed sample Invoice [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig8QE.png), and my class like that

```
public partial class Invoice
{
    public Invoice()
    {
        this.InvoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
    }

    public int code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> inv_date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> discount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> net { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
}

public partial class InvoiceDetails
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> itemId { get; set; }
    public string itemName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> request_quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> vendorId { get; set; }

    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        this.InvoiceDetails = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> vendorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}

    public partial class Vendor
{
    public Vendor()
    {
        this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and finally class is collecting 3 class Invoice , InvoiceDetails and vendor

```
public class Collection_invoice
{
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public InvoiceDetail InvoiceDetail { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Vendor> Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

I using this class inside view model to create new invoice and everything is good, but if the invoice have two items or more it just save only final item was add like that

[Only last item will be insert in database ... how to solve that ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3PVW.png)

My question what the change I must be needed to save all items inside the invoice in SQL server... Please help..

and this is view model for create new invoice(last image)

```
@model PurchasesInvoice.Models.Collection_invoice
@using (Html.BeginForm())
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Invoice.code)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Invoice.code, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m)
                        <br />
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Invoice.InvoiceDetails,
                        new SelectList(Model.Vendor, "id", "name"), "Select Vendor", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary", @onchange = "Get_Items()", @required = "required" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label("Invoice Date")
                        <br />
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Invoice.inv_date, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Invoice.inv_date, " ", new { @class = "req" })
                    </div>
                </div>

<table class="direction table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Item Id")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Item Name")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Price")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Quantity")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Request quantity")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Total")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Action")

                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceDetail.itemId, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "item_Id", @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("itemId", new List<SelectListItem>{
                                        new SelectListItem{Text ="-- Select Item --", Value=" "} },
                                            "-- Select Item --", new { @class = "dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary", @required = "required", @onchange = "Get_dataItem()" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceDetail.price, new { @id = "price", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBox("quantity", " ", new { @id = "quantity", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceDetail.request_quantity, " ", new { @id = "request_quantity", @onchange = "calculateQuantity()", @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InvoiceDetail.request_quantity, " ", new { @class = "req" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InvoiceDetail.total, new { @id = "total", @readonly = "readonly", @class = "label-info form-control" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button id="btnAddItem" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Item</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<table id="table-items" class="direction table table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Item Id")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Item Name")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Price")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Quantity")
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayName("Total")
                            </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Invoice.total)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Invoice.total, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Invoice.discount)
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Invoice.discount, new { @onchange = "CalculateNetInvoice()", @class = "form-control" })<span>%</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Invoice.discount, "", new { @class = "req" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Invoice.net)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Invoice.net, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <br />
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btnInsert" name="btnInsert" value="Save Invoice" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Collection_invoice coInvoice)
    {
        if (coInvoice.Invoice != null)
        {
            Invoice inv = new Invoice();
            inv.inv_date = coInvoice.Invoice.inv_date;
            inv.net = coInvoice.Invoice.net;
            inv.total = coInvoice.Invoice.total;
            inv.discount = coInvoice.Invoice.discount;

            int code = inv.AddNewInvoice(inv);

            coInvoice.InvoiceDetail.code = code;
            coInvoice.InvoiceDetail.itemName = db.Items.SingleOrDefault(im => im.id == coInvoice.InvoiceDetail.itemId).name;
            db.InvoiceDetails.Add(coInvoice.InvoiceDetail);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            var VendorList = db.Vendors.ToList();
            var invoice_detalis = new Models.Collection_invoice
            {
                Vendor = VendorList
            };
            return View("Create", invoice_detalis);
        }
        int? page = null;
        return View("List", db.Invoices.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full code of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you using invoiceDetails as list of objects you should override  set function to insert in database

Comment: What does your controller post method look like? Can you include that in your example?